# How to run/deploy Google AppEngine Managed vms using Gradle

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud

I've pushed, run and tested a managed VM with custom runtime as an AppEngine application. Now I want to make it multi-module, with the default module being a Google Cloud Endpoint configured to work with Android. Hence, I'm using Gradle as my build system.

Now, I noticed that Google has made some initial commits for gcloud preview app run/deploy into the gradle-appengine-plugin:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/commit/2e4a2b8abb7ec7905012f1f9c12adea7010a41b7

How do I use this extension? Do I add a section to my build.gradle like this?

```
appengine {
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
    gcloud {
        project = 'projectId?'
        app {
            dockerHost = tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
            version = 1.4.1
            server = //What goes here?
        }

    }
}
```

Or have I got it entirely wrong?

Please guide me on how to use this.

Also, how in specific do I setup the build.gradle rules for a "custom vm" which is not based off of a standard java runtime? (Since I can't just package an app.yaml and Dockerfile into a war folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid this for now, the gcloud part of the plugin is still being worked out. As for the "server" flag, from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/deploy), you don't really need to specify that.

There are two options you can try for running the deploy though:

1. Use gcloud directly for now (from the command line).
2. You could try an Exec task in Gradle to call into your gcloud, You can get the webapp directory by doing `AppEnginePlugin.getExplodedAppDirectory(project).absolute path`

You'd have to add the [Exec task](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) to your build file to hook it in. It might look like this :

**build.gradle**

```
task gcloudExec1(type:Exec) {
    commandline 'gcloud', 'preview', 'app', 'deploy'
    args "--dockerHost=tcp:"
    args "--version=1.4.1"
    ....
    args AppEnginePlugin.getExplodedAppDir(project).absolutepath
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add this to each module's build.gradle file, or my ear module's build.gradle? If so, how would I run/deploy both the war modules together?

Comment: I don't think this will work with EAR deployments as gcloud is language agnostic and EARs are a java construct.

You'd probably have to put it in each module and configure the args correctly.

If you name them all the same, it'll run it on every module that has it defined.

Comment: Alright. I guess I'm stuck on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441545/appengine-java-multi-modules-sample-error-on-gcloud-preview-app-run till I know what the right arguments are. I'll test it out after I get the commandline working and comment/accept. Thanks!